# Dealing with users who use questions to express their criticism of Islam/Muslims

Tags: discussion, moderation, questions, criticism

This is about users who use the site to post and express their or other people's (typically negative) views and opinions about Islam/Muslims.

For example, several of [BROY](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/195/broy)'s posts have a clearly non-constructive tone. The user writes rants to express what non-Muslims think about Islam and frames them as questions about Islam. For example

> https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/929/why-the-history-of-muslims-is-the-most-shameful-in-the-world

says:

> Muslims assassinated almost all of their rightly guided Caliphs.
>   Muslims engaged in wars among themselves and became divided into
>   various sects only within 30 years of the death of the prophet.
>
> There is no place of monarchy, dictatorship and autocracy in Islam.
>   But Muslims embraced monarchy and it continued through 3 major lines
>   of inheritance (Umaiyad, Abbasid, Ottoman). And, I don't need to
>   comment about dictatorships and autocracies.
>
> Muslims are the most uneducated, corrupt, undeveloped and lagged
>   nation.
>
> Why are these things so?
>
> Some may include colonialism, invasion by westerners, etc. as the
>   reasons. What forbade Muslims to do the same thing to their colonists
>   and invaders? Are you that much honest and harmless?
>
> Why the preachers of Christianity gives education, health-care,
>   monetary supports to others? Why Muslims want to preach Islam by
>   suicide bombings?
>
> If USA and Israel is treading Muslims, what forbade you achieve your
>   economic and military strength like Japan and China?
>
> Why Muslims only sell oil, eat and sleep?
>
> Why Saudi Arabia doesn't have any Ministry of Science and Technology?

Aside from stereotyping Muslims and prejudice against Islam and Muslims, this is more a post to express the users (or other people's) views about Islam, not really asking a question. (Moreover the user [insists](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/937/were-the-9-wives-of-the-prophet-puh-really-needed) on keeping the rants in the posts.)

I think it should be made clear to such users that this is not the place to write such posts. This is not a debate/discussion site, nor a site to criticize Islam/Muslims. It is for people who genuinely want to learn about Islam from Islamic perspective(s) to ask questions, not for expressing or discussing what others think about Islam/Muslims.

If a user has a question about Islam or historical Islamic figures (like the prophet) it is fine to ask with a non-offensive and constructive tone.

Writing posts to express the criticism made by non-Muslims about Islam should not be permitted.

I suggest that in such cases,

1. The moderators contact the user and give a warning about the behavior,
2. The non-constructive questions posted by the user either should be closed as as such or get edited to remove the parts which are rants about Islam/Muslims,
3. The user should get banned in case posting with non-constructive tone continues (after receiving the warning).

Comment: This is a great point and idea. I've seen such cases a lot, e.g. [why are Muslims so aggressive?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/806/why-are-some-muslims-so-aggressive). If there's no intention, the OP must reword the question so that it makes more sense!

Answer (score 5):

**I agree.**

Rants like this are not welcome on this site, and that seems to be what his posts are. Eventually, he will get banned by a mod if his questions keep getting closed and are downvoted.

When we get mods, I do expect them to confront users like this.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is a religious site. You should have well accepted that something like this is bound to happen.
If you look at other sites around the internet the frequency is much, much higher than what we are seeing here. Some don't stop here, they proceed to newspapers or tv channels (youtube has 'em).

**How do we deal with them?**
(In order of increasing intensity)

- Close votes on their questions & downvotes too.
- Users ask the to remove the content as a comment to their question/answer
- If no heed is paid and similar posts still continue as a mod to ban that user (We have Robert for us now). We can start by flagging his post as a hate speech. it will automatically attract a mods attention. if not you can always e-mail a mod (they have their email id on their profile page). But i doubt banning is helpful as they will come up with a new account.

Comment: -1 This is NOT a religious site, it's a site for knowledge about a religion.

Answer (score -3):

@Kaveh  Why do you not invite Him to chat or privet chat and discuss it with him before you post this, Tell him what you said in this post moderators do not have to do all the work.  If we are a community than one warns the other and so on.

Comment: I have already done something [similar](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/937/42). I improve one of his later questions and explained this is not a place to write such posts but the BROY rolled back the edit.

Comment: did you invite him to chat?

Comment: Meta is the place to discuss these issue not chat. The reason I posted this on the meta in place of just flagging for moderator attention is to have dealt with the issue publicly, so we can refer back to this in case we face similar users in future (which I think will happen).

Comment: Yes, but did you tell him all you said in this post before posting it?  and you are not addressing him directly.  A community member address another directly, not asking someone else to do it for you.  If you see a problem try to change it, that is the sunnah.

Comment: The comments on the question were for BROY. This meta-post is not. Based on my experience as a moderator this is a better way to deal with these cases, particularly because I think this is going to happen with other users in future: people will try to frame their opinions, criticism, and rant about Islam in the form of a question.

Comment: @Kaveh I am sorry, but it would seem to me that you are tattling on him.  Are you understanding what I am trying to say?

Comment: That is not my intention. What I see is a continued behavior of non-constructive posts and the insistence on continuing it. What I can do is to edit the meta-question and change it to be more general, still it is not unusual to discuss inappropriate behavior of users on meta, particularly when it is likely to happen again by other users.

Comment: ok please edit it, and leave the question out and do not say about this user, try to make it face toward the user.

Comment: As I said this is not for the user and stating this towards the community is the usual practice on SE sites.

Comment: I see both of you are right, but you should waste your energy trying to make him understand, it is sunnah that if you see something is a problem try to change it.  Than you can bring it up to the community.  Anymore comments on this please give it in chat

Comment: I understand your good intentions, I would be happy to see a change of behavior by such users, one can extract genuine questions from his posts without the rants. (Btw, the chat is a place for personal user discussions, the meta is the place for discussions about the site and its policies, remember that many users don't go over the chat logs to see what has been discussed in them, if you want to state something important that users generally should be aware of you should eventually post it on the meta.)